# Line feed in the results of the shell script using grep command

Tags: linux, shell, script, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am writing a shell script to `grep` something from a log file and then print all the results using `echo` command.

I could do that but suppose log contain more than 1 instance of the search string then it prints all the results in one line. Is it possible to print the results with line feed; if I simply execute the `grep` command in the shell then it will print with line feed so I thought with shell script also it will work same way but clearly that's not happening.

**My shell scripts:**

```
#!/bin/bash
messageStr='a senior leader of '$2
echo $messageStr
results=`grep "$messageStr" $1`
echo "results= " $results
```

**My log file:**

```
A column written for ndtv.com by Ashutosh, a senior leader of Aam Aadmi Party or AAP, triggered protests from the opposition today and an order to appear before the country's top women's rights body, which said he has demeaned women.

a senior leader of Aam Aadmi Party or AAP

A column written for ndtv.com by Ashutosh, a senior leader of Aam Aadmi Party or AAP, triggered protests from the opposition today and an order to appear before the country's top women's rights body, which said he has demeaned women.
```

**Actual results:**

```
results=  A column written for ndtv.com by Ashutosh, a senior leader of Aam Aadmi Party or AAP, triggered protests from the opposition today and an order to appear before the country's top women's rights body, which said he has demeaned women. a senior leader of Aam Aadmi Party or AAP
```

**Expected results:**

```
results=  A column written for ndtv.com by Ashutosh, a senior leader of Aam Aadmi Party or AAP, triggered protests from the opposition today and an order to appear before the country's top women's rights body, which said he has demeaned women. 
a senior leader of Aam Aadmi Party or AAP
```

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unquoted variables are subjected to word splitting (after the shell parameter is expanded, spaces, tabs and newline characters are used to split the expanded variable into separate arguments) and globbing (expansion of shell wildcard symbols). As a rule, you should *always **double-quote** shell variables* unless you specifically want word splitting and/or globbing. For more information, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

If I understand your question correctly, in this case, you just need to quote the `$results` parameter:

```
messageStr="a senior leader of $2"
echo "$messageStr"
results=$(grep "$messageStr" "$1")
echo "results=  $results"
```

By the way, using back-ticks is (effectively) deprecated for command substitution; it’s best to use `$()`.

*Addendum*: http://shellcheck.net/ provides very useful feedback when developing shell scripts (e.g., highlighting unquoted variables).

Comment: Thanks, that was very nice answer with explanation and reference.

Comment: @hagrawal you're welcome.  I've just edited my answer to add a link to the very useful shellcheck tool.